# How can I move my character's foot in the direction I chose with a key input?

Tags: game-engine, armature, bones

I'm trying to make a game with some aspects similar to octodad but for this to work I need something that will allow me to move my characters foot in the direction I chose with a key input, it may seem simple but I'm a bit of a noob.

Comment: Are you asking about how to use the Blender game engine?

Answer (score 0):

I am new as well. But i am pretty sure you would not create the event in blender, but a game engine.

To explain, in Blender you would create an animation of, lets say a swinging sword, and save that animation to your model.

Now that your model has an animation you would load your model into a game engine (such as Unity or UE4) and in the game engine you would setup your input handler (When i click, play swinging sword animation)

Like I said, I am new as well so I probably need someone to confirm.

Comment: They already know they need the game engine - the question is tagged with 'game-engine'.

Comment: Well alright then ...

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, all i needed to do was put a copy location constrsaint on an empty and map that empties movement to my key (;